# Django Admin "TypeError int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Car'"

Tags: django, python-3.x, admin

My project Admin worked fine, but since I've been working to link images to my model objects, it's raising this error. The specific error code is common when dealing with models, but none I've seen address the admin site in specific.

So far, I've tried making a new migration with the new class, which went fine, and also deleting some admin fields.

**models.py Car model** 
There's a lot I've skipped, but nothing I've changed since it was last working.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    car_model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    vin = models.CharField('VIN', max_length=17, help_text='Enter the 17 character VIN number.', blank=True, null=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mileage')
    car_images = models.ImageField(help_text='Upload pictures', upload_to=image_directory_path, storage=image_storage)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    engine_displacement = models.CharField(default=2.0, max_length=3, help_text="Engine displacement in Liters (E.g. 2.0, 4.2, 6.3)")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
    help_text="Unique ID for this car")
...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_added']
        permissions = (("can_change_availability", "Mark car as sold"),)  

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.manufacturer} {self.car_model}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('showroom:car-detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

**admin.py code**

```
@admin.register(Car)
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer', 'model', 'model_year', 'mileage', 'status', 'date_added', 'price', 'seller')
    list_filter = ('manufacturer', 'status', 'transmission')
    fieldsets = (
        ('General information', {
            'fields': ('car_images', 'manufacturer', 'model',
            'model_year', 'price', 'vin', 'mileage', 'transmission', 'engine_displacement', 
            'forced_induction', 'drivetrain', 'description', 'id',)
        }),
       ('Availability', {
            'fields': ('status', 'seller')
        }),
    )
```

**This is the TemplateError**

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 62
   int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Car'
   52 :             {% endblock %}
   53 :         </div>
   54 :         {% endif %}
   55 :         {% endblock %}
   56 :         {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
   57 :     </div>
   58 :     <!-- END Header -->
   59 :     {% block breadcrumbs %}
   60 :     <div class="breadcrumbs">
   61 :     <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
   62 :     {% if title %} &rsaquo; {{ title }}{% endif %}
   63 :     </div>
   64 :     {% endblock %}
   65 :     {% endif %}
   66 : 
   67 :     {% block messages %}
   68 :         {% if messages %}
   69 :         <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
   70 :           <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
   71 :         {% endfor %}</ul>
   72 :         {% endif %}

...
During handling of the above exception ('manufacturer'), another exception occurred:
...

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/showroom/car/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Car'
```

Comment: there is extra space  at line 62 `{% if t itle %} &rsaquo; {{  title }}{% endif %}` . see at word `title`. Your word is `t itle`.

Comment: I see. But I didn't write that code, I guess it's part of the in-built admin HTML

Comment: you can't write `t itle`, It should be `title`.

Comment: I've just reviewed it. The error code formatting caused the odd spacing. I've fixed it now.